# Haskell: abort writeFile on error

Tags: haskell, error-handling, io

I have a program that generates JSON and prints it to file.  The function that generates the JSON can fail midway through the code generation.

At the moment when there is a failure in the JSON generation, the code that is generated up to that point still gets written to a file, giving me an incomplete/incorrect output file.

I am trying to figure out how to prevent the bad output from being written. Something like:

```
main = do
  let
     output          =  encodingfunction
     print' (Just x) =  writeFile "outputfile" output
     print' _        =  putStrLn "Encoding Failed Miserably"
  print' ouput
  return ()

encodingfunction :: Maybe String
```

Comment: You need `encodingFunction` to change, returning `Maybe String` instead of returning a `String` that might have an error in at at some point.

Comment: @amalloy I have made a change to the `encodingfunction` and I still have the same issue.  Do I have to change every single function in my program to `Maybe` type ?

Comment: As written, your code should work, although you should be using `x` rather than `output` in your `writeFile` call. If you're still having problems, please produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example])http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so answerers can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna force the evaluation of the returned string so that the encoding function is for sure done before you start writing to the file. Mabye you could check its length before printing it.